# Auto create constructor body and fields in Netbeans based on signature

Tags: java, netbeans

If I start from an empty class (TestClass) in Netbeans and add the following empty constructor:

```
public void TestClass(String a, String b) {
}
```

is there a way to have netbeans automagically generate:

```
private final String a;
private final String b;

public void TestClass(String a, String b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

I know that I can first create the 2 members and ask netbeans to auto-generate the constructor but I'm asking for the other way round.

For example, in eclipse, this can be achieved by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> on the constructor's argument > assign parameter to new field.

Comment: I didn't understand the question

Comment: I write the constructor's signature (TestClass(String, String)) and I want Netbeans to figure out that my class needs two private final strings that need to be assigned from the constructor's parameters.

Comment: I don't think that anyone implemented something like that since you can do many other things with two strings in the ctor

Comment: I have right next to me, on the wall, this document printed: http://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf
and I don't see anything like that

Comment: @alfasin the constructor looks fairly standard to me - thanks for the shortcuts link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write the empty constructor with the required signature. Then set the cursor next to a parameter and press Alt+ENTER.

NetBeans will ask to create a new field. Press ENTER and NetBeans will write the code for you.

I think you have to do it for each parameter separately, but I'm not sure.

Generally, Alt+ENTER in NetBeans is similar to Ctrl+1 in Eclipse, also at other places.

Comment: Is this only for Java? It doesn't work for my PHP-edition of NetBeans.

Answer (score 9):

from: https://coderwall.com/p/oyanzg

Just point the cursor at the point where you want the generated code to appear, and press Alt + Insert (or select Source -> Insert Code). The following menu will appear, where you can choose to generate whatever you want:

[image]

Comment: Yes! In this case, start by declaring your class variables, then generate the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

for mac users :

highlight the variables then press control + i

then choose the option you want